# Symfony swift_mail: send to multiple address but only display one address per email

Tags: php, symfony, email

I want to send an email to a list of address but I want each person to receive the email with his email address in to: (and not with the other email addresses of the diffusion list).
I am using symfony and Swift mail. My code look like that at the moment (it is working):

```
public function sendmail(Notification $notification, $alert){
            $to = array();

            foreach ($members as $member) {
                $to[] = $member->getUser()->getEmail();  
            }

            $html = $this->templating->render(
                'PlatformBundle:Emails:email.html.twig',
                array('alert' => $alert, 'notification' => $notification, 'user' => $this->user)
            );          

            // Configure and send the mail
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('an email ')
            ->setFrom($this->sender_email)
            ->setCc($this->user->getEmail())
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setBody($html, 'text/html');

            $mailStatus = $this->mailer->send($message);
}
```

I have 2 solutions (I do not like any for them!).

1. using BCC ([Sending to multiple Email addresses but displaying only one C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219965/sending-to-multiple-email-addresses-but-displaying-only-one-c-sharp)) but it makes my email looking like a spam
2. looping and sending the same email to each member (seems really server resource consuming)

   ```
   public function sendmail(Notification $notification, $alert){
           $to = array();

           foreach ($members as $member) {
               $to[] = $member->getUser()->getEmail();  

               $html = $this->templating->render(
                   'PlatformBundle:Emails:email.html.twig',
                   array('alert' => $alert, 'notification' => $notification, 'user' => $this->user)
               );          

               // Configure and send the mail
               $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
               ->setSubject('an email ')
               ->setFrom($this->sender_email)
               ->setCc($this->user->getEmail())
               ->setTo($to)
               ->setBody($html, 'text/html');

               $mailStatus = $this->mailer->send($message);
           }
   ```

Is this loop OK?

Any better idea?

Comment: What about [Bcc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy)? Why would a message with only one (visible) recipient look spam?

Comment: "However, only putting email addresses in the Bcc field, with no address (or your own address) in the To field, may cause the message to be flagged as Spam by some junk email filters."

Comment: The BCC method has a limit on the number of BCC'ed addresses ; and it is indeed sometimes marked as spam on some mail servers (I have tried it a while ago).

Comment: How many mails do you want to send in one go ?

Comment: around 50 to  100 email per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping is really the only solution.

If you have many recipients, you will be marked as spam (and banned) pretty fast. You will want to go through a dedicated mail platform (with a bit of time between each send), which you can code yourself (pretty heavy work), or there are many mail platform as service around, like MailChimp or MailJet for instance.

It all depends on the number of mails to send. Up to about 100 per day might be OK (although it's an arbitrary number from the top of my head).
More than a certain threshold, and depending on the mail server you use (local on your server or gmail for instance), your IP or account might get banned. Most email providers have a mail limit per day, for instance.

Email services have many rules for sending, for instance, they delay the emails ; they send using multiple domains and addresses ; they work with the main mail providers (gmail, yahoo...) to make sure their domains are not marked as spam automatically...

Basically, if you really want to send many emails to many people, I really don't recommend doing it yourself. There are too many caveats.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I added my loop in my question. Shall I set  time between send?

Comment: It depends on the number of mails to send. Up to about 100 per day might be OK. More than a certain threshold, and depending on the mail server you use (local on your server or gmail for instance), and your IP or account might get banned. Most email providers have a mail limit per day, for instance.

Comment: I just tried the loop above: all my emails are marked as spam; i just realised that on my loop I am incrementing the element $to...

Comment: I have updated my answer to add more details on the matter.